# AngularJs- I don't want to request on url but just add or change a key value in parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm new to **AngularJs** and **Rails**,

I want to add a parameter key or change a previous key value in my browser `URL`, without making any request on that `URL`.

Please suggest some best way to do this from **angularjs controller**.

Comment: please explain more...

Answer (score 0):

if you are using anguler-ui-router than you can do it

```
$state.go($state.$current, {key: new_value}, {reload:true, inherit: false});
```

for that, you must have defined params while defining a state as below

```
$stateProvider
  .state('alpha', {
    url: '/alpha',
    templateUrl: 'whatever.html',
    controller: 'whateverController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    params: {key: false} //add reload param to a view you want to reload
  });
```

Comment: This is making request to reload the url when changing from angularJs controller

Comment: Why add key false, However I want to reload and access the page when I hit enter through browser url However I don't want to reload page when I add or change any of url key from my controller

Comment: try with `{reload:false}`. AFAIK you can not change the URL parameter until you do not reload it

Comment: you can add `{key :undefined}` but you need to define it  in .state, that is must

Comment: I have defined parameters in state I don't want to reload when some parameter change from my controller however I want to load same url when I hit from browser url

Answer (score 0):

Use the [$location service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

> The `$location` service:
>
> Exposes the current URL in the browser address bar, so you can
>
> - Watch and observe the URL.
> - Change the URL.
>
> [— AngularJS $location Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

> #### What does it not do?
>
> It does not cause a full page reload when the browser URL is changed. To reload the page after changing the URL, use the lower-level API, `$window.location.href`.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Using `$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)